# Adding geom_line between data points with different geom_boxplot fill variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have a much larger data frame but a sample dummy df is as follows:

```
set.seed(23)
df = data.frame(name = c(rep("Bob",8),rep("Tom",8)),
                topic = c(rep(c("Reading","Writing"),8)),
                subject = c(rep(c("English","English","Spanish","Spanish"),4)),
                exam = c(rep("First",4),rep("Second",4),rep("First",4),rep("Second",4)),
                score = sample(1:100,16))
```

I have to plot it in the way shown in the picture below (for my original data frame) but with lines connecting the scores corresponding to each name between the first and second class in the exam variable, I tried `geom_line(aes(group=name))` but the lines are not connected in the right way. Is there any way to connect the points that also respects the grouping by the `fill` variable similar to how the `position_dodge()` helps separate the points by their fill grouping? Thanks a lot!

```
library(ggplot2)
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=topic,y=score,fill=exam)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
    geom_point(size=1.75,position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
    facet_grid(~subject,switch = "y")
```

[image]

Comment: You need `geom_path` rather than `geom_line`, and you should get what you want with the `group` aesthetic set to the right combination of variable (you can use `:` to combine factors)

Comment: Something like `geom_path(aes(x=topic,y=score,group=factor(name):factor(topic):factor(subject))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to `group` the lines by `name` and `topic` and do the dodging of lines manually instead of relying on `position_dogde`. To this end convert `topic` to a numeric for the `geom_line` and shift the position by the necessary amount to align the lines with the dodged points:

```r
set.seed(23)
df <- data.frame(
  name = c(rep("Bob", 8), rep("Tom", 8)),
  topic = c(rep(c("Reading", "Writing"), 8)),
  subject = c(rep(c("English", "English", "Spanish", "Spanish"), 4)),
  exam = c(rep("First", 4), rep("Second", 4), rep("First", 4), rep("Second", 4)),
  score = sample(1:100, 16)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = topic, y = score, fill = exam)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(size = 1.75, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)) +
  geom_line(aes(
    x = as.numeric(factor(topic)) + .75 / 4 * ifelse(exam == "First", -1, 1),
    group = interaction(name, topic)
  )) +
  facet_grid(~subject, switch = "y")
```

[image]